# input type="image" padding issue in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Below is my HTML and CSS. This works on all browsers except IE7. The `width` and `height` are dimension of button.gif. On all other browsers, the image is added to the input field with padding around (so that the button is wider with the image in the middle) and is vertically aligned to the bottom of the parent div. This does not work in IE7. In IE7, the total size of the input field is 15px x 15px and the paddings are totally ignored.

```
<input class="input-button" type="image" src="../images/button.gif" />

.input-button {
width:15px;
height:15px;
background-color:#000;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;
padding:4px 20px 5px;
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: You do have a valid DOCTYPE for your page? Otherwise, IE drops into quirks mode. I came across a suggestion to add a fake border `border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;`. I've no idea if this would fix your issue, but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @AndrewGibson Yes you are right. I missed the DOCTYPE. Thanks for pointing that out. Now it seems to work well. I thought I didn't need DOCTYPE for HTML5 type declaration `<html>`. Anyway works now. Thanks!

Comment: `<html>` is the opening html-tag, all documents still require a DOCTYPE declaration as the first line on the page. Glad it's sorted ;)

Answer (score -1):

use the prefix "-ms-" before ur codes and write them again.
under your .input-button add -ms-width:15px and so on for all statments or which ever u think is not wrking for ie.in your case you wil onli need to add this statement

```
-ms-padding:4px 20px 5px;
```